# How can I load a content when it comes into the viewport using JavaScript or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I made a staggering animation to the h1 element using a function, now I want the animation to occur when the h1 element comes into the viewport when the user scrolls down.

By the time the user scrolls down the page, the animation has already occurred.

I want the animation to occur only when the h1 element enters the viewport.

```js
var textWrapper = document.querySelector(".text");
            textWrapper.innerHTML = textWrapper.textContent.replace(
                /\S/g,
                "<span class='letter'>$&</span>"
            );

            anime.timeline().add({
                targets: ".text .letter",
                translateY: [100, 0],
                translateZ: 0,
                opacity: [0, 1],
                easing: "easeOutExpo",
                duration: 2000,
                delay: (el, i) => 60 * i,
            });
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.text .letter {
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 1em;
}

.page1{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

.page2{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>LNPD02</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/2.1.3/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/2.0.2/anime.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>

    <div class="page1">
      <h1>Scroll down</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="page2">
      <h1 class="text">Animated Text</h1>
    </div>

  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Load a function or run one? Consider reading into https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript's IntersectionObserver will alert you when a particular element comes into the viewport.

This snippet does what the code in the question does with the addition of waiting for the text to enter the viewport before the animation is set up.

```js
var textWrapper = document.querySelector(".text");
textWrapper.innerHTML = textWrapper.textContent.replace(
  /\S/g,
  "<span class='letter'>$&</span>"
);
let callback = (entries, observer) => {
  entries.forEach(entry => {
    // See MDN for more detail on IntersectionObserver
    // Each entry describes an intersection change for one observed
    // target element:
    //   entry.boundingClientRect
    //   entry.intersectionRatio
    //   entry.intersectionRect
    //   entry.isIntersecting
    //   entry.rootBounds
    //   entry.target
    //   entry.time
    if (entry.isIntersecting) {

      anime.timeline().add({
        targets: ".text .letter",
        translateY: [100, 0],
        translateZ: 0,
        opacity: [0, 1],
        easing: "easeOutExpo",
        duration: 2000,
        delay: (el, i) => 60 * i,
      });
    }
  });
};
let observer = new IntersectionObserver(callback);
observer.observe(textWrapper);
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.text .letter {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 1em;
}

.page1 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

.page2 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>LNPD02</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/2.1.3/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/2.0.2/anime.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="page1">
    <h1>Scroll down</h1>
  </div>

  <div class="page2">
    <h1 class="text">Animated Text</h1>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks mate ! It works as just as I expected.